# How to install "Seshat" by using g++

Tags: c++, g++, installation

I want to install seshat which is OCR engine for math equation.

I use windows 10. I already install "boost 1.17.0", "MinGW" for g++ compile.

The followings are installation guide for seshat,

1.Obtain the package using git:~~ (done)

2.Go to the directory containing the source code.(done)

3.If the include files of boost libraries are not in the path, add it to the FLAGS variable in the file Makefile ("-I/path/to/boost/").

4.Compile seshat

$ make

(https://github.com/falvaro/seshat)

As in 3, I tried to add to path in makefile, but it does'n work.

(Makefile)

'CC=g++

LINK=-lxerces-c -lm

FLAGS = -O3 -Wno-unused-result #-I/path/to/boost/'

..............................................

In my think, 'FLAGS' is boost path, so, I tried to edit like as

'FLAGS = D:/.../boost/',

'FLAGS = "D:/.../boost/"',

'FLAGS = -O3 -Wno-unused-result #-I D:/.../boost/'.....

Indeed, I have never studied C++ before.

Next, I tried to compile like as

'D:...\seshat-master>g++ seshat.cc'

and get the following error message ;)

```
`In file included from symrec.h:30,
                 from production.h:28,
                 from grammar.h:27,
                 from seshat.cc:21:
rnnlib4seshat/DataSequence.hpp:47:10: fatal error: boost/bimap.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/bimap.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.`
```

please, help me. ㅠㅠ

Comment: "boost 1.17.0" sounds rather ancient  current is 1.70.0

Comment: @Öö Tiib your right,^^; I downloaded 1.70.0, not 1.17.0

Comment: When you use makefiles then you should compile like "make" not like "g++ seshat.cc" (that does call compiler directly).

Comment: @Öö Tiib where should I type "make"? The "make" works in window computer? please, could give me some more advise?

Comment: Type make in the directory where you made FLAGS in Makefile to look something like FLAGS = -O3 -Wno-unused-result -ID:/kjs/boost_1_70_0/    It seems that  you also try to omit -I or add space between -I and D: or /boost/ to end of the path, or the "" around flags, don't do such things.